# Applications of Signal and System theory

Tags: signal-processing, linear-systems

I recently heard a lecture about Signals and Systems and find the subject extremely exciting. I would like to do more in this direction, so I would be interested to know in which modern research area of physics one needs a lot of Signal and System theory, since this is not clear to me from the lecture.

Comment: You are dealing with applications, which is probably an engineering function.  Look in the area of process control to get one example.

Comment: @DavidWhite Most of the work behind any physics investigation is applied physics. Also, math is math. The same math concepts show up in more abstract physics. It works both ways: it can be illuminating to analyze signal filters using Dirac notation if that's what you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

It's very important in instrumentation and data analysis. [This paper](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1979Natur.282..240W/abstract) used a matched filter method that Bill Wheaton and I came up with to dig a spectrum out of some rather crappy data. This caused a colleague to accuse us of witchcraft (ツ), but she was able to confirm and extend our result using better data and more traditional methods.

[Similar ideas](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1980AJ.....85.1421H/abstract) are behind the extreme sensitivity of the CCD detectors used in astronomy.

You may also find control theory useful if you need to control something like the temperature of your sensor or the direction your spacecraft is pointing.